# How much memory can Nodejs manage on the RAM?

Tags: node.js

Suppose I have 80 GB RAM, can a single process of nodejs use 50 GB RAM?

Does NodeJS do *paging* between RAM and SSD?

---

I tried to test it on my macbook pro with 16 gb RAM and 256 free SSD:

I tried to allocate 200 GB on my ram:

```
var arrayOfPointers = []

const mb = 1024*1024

for(let i=0;i<1024*200;i++){
    arrayOfPointers.push(new Buffer(mb))
}

console.log(arrayOfPointers.length)
```

The code run successfully. How can it be?

---

- The question is - Can Nodejs efficiently do it, **not if it's recommended or not**.
- nodejs version: `v14.15.4`